# Multiple shared_ptr storing same pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Consider this program:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class X
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<X>
{
public:
  struct Cleanup1 { void operator()(X*) const; };
  struct Cleanup2 { void operator()(X*) const; };
  std::shared_ptr<X> lock1();
  std::shared_ptr<X> lock2();
};

std::shared_ptr<X> X::lock1()
{
  std::cout << "Resource 1 locked" << std::endl;
  return std::shared_ptr<X>(this, Cleanup1());
}

std::shared_ptr<X> X::lock2()
{
  std::cout << "Resource 2 locked" << std::endl;
  return std::shared_ptr<X>(this, Cleanup2());
}

void X::Cleanup1::operator()(X*) const
{
  std::cout << "Resource 1 unlocked" << std::endl;
}

void X::Cleanup2::operator()(X*) const
{
  std::cout << "Resource 2 unlocked" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  X x;
  std::shared_ptr<X> p1 = x.lock1();
  {
    std::shared_ptr<X> p2 = x.lock2();
  }
}
```

I don't see anything in the C++11 Standard section 20.7.2 suggesting any of this is invalid.  It's a bit unusual to have two `shared_ptr` objects store the same pointer `&x` but not share ownership, and to use "deleters" that do not end the lifetime of `*get()`, but nothing forbids it.  (And if either of those are entirely unintended, it would be difficult to explain why some `shared_ptr` member functions accept a `std::nullptr_t` value.)  And as expected, the program outputs:

```
Resource 1 locked
Resource 2 locked
Resource 2 unlocked
Resource 1 unlocked
```

But now if I add a bit to `main()`:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  X x;
  std::shared_ptr<X> p1 = x.lock1();
  bool test1( x.shared_from_this() );
  std::cout << "x.shared_from_this() not empty: " << test1 << std::endl;
  {
    std::shared_ptr<X> p2 = x.lock2();
  }
  try {
    bool test2( x.shared_from_this() );
    std::cout << "x.shared_from_this() not empty: " << test2 << std::endl;
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

then things get trickier.  With g++ 4.6.3, I get the output:

```
Resource 1 locked
x.shared_from_this() not empty: true
Resource 2 locked
Resource 2 unlocked
caught: std::bad_weak_ptr
Resource 1 unlocked
```

Why would the second call to `shared_from_this()` fail?  All the requirements of 20.7.2.4p7 are met:

> *Requires:* `enable_shared_from_this<T>` shall be an accessible base class of `T`. `*this` shall be a subobject of an object `t` of type `T`.  There shall be at least one `shared_ptr` instance `p` that *owns* `&t`.

[`T` is `X`, `t` is `x`, `p` is `p1`.]

But g++'s `enable_shared_from_this` essentially follows the suggested implementation from the (non-normative) "Note" in 20.7.2.4p10, using a private `weak_ptr` member in class `enable_shared_from_this`.  And it seems impossible to account for this sort of issue without doing something considerably more complicated in `enable_shared_from_this`.

Is this a defect in the Standard?  (If so, no comment is needed here on what the solution "should" be: add a requirement so the example program invokes Undefined Behavior, change the Note to not suggest such a simple implementation would be sufficient,....)

Comment: From a standards perspective, I'm not sure.  The reason WHY is that the g++ (and boost) implementation expect that the first time you create a shared pointer from a given raw pointer instance of X will be the only time, and the weak_ptr private variable is set to point to that created instance.  When you create a second new shared pointer on the same instance in `lock2()`, it overwrites the original weak_ptr, and when it unlocks, the weak pointer now points at nothing, hence the error.

Comment: The non-normative note that demonstrates an example implementation of `enable_from_this` concludes (on paragraph 11) with "The shared_ptr constructors that create **unique pointers** can detect the presence of an `enable_shared_from_this` base and assign the newly created `shared_ptr` to its `__weak_this` member." [emphasis mine] I find it remarkable that this note wasn't worded with something to the effect of "the constructors that create *owning* pointers", and I wonder what's a unique `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Luc I believe that's referring to the constructors that after creation would return true from their `unique()`.  Basically, the constructors that take initial ownership from either a raw pointer or a unique_ptr.

Comment: @LucDanton: A unique `shared_ptr` is well-defined; it's a `shared_ptr` who's `shared_ptr::unique` method returns `true`. IE: one who's `use_count() ==1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree this is a hole in the specification, thus a defect. It's basically the same as http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2179 although that issue comes at it from a slightly different (and IMHO more obviously broken) angle.

I'm not sure I agree that this is a misuse of `shared_ptr`, I think it's fine to do that with shared_ptrs, because unlike the code in issue 2179 you use no-op deleters. I think the problem is when you try to combine that kind of use of `shared_ptr` with `enable_shared_from_this`.

So my first thought was to fix it by extending the requirements of `shared_from_this`:

> *Requires:* `enable_shared_from_this<T>` shall be an accessible base class of `T`. `*this` shall be a subobject of an object `t` of type `T`.  There shall be at least one `shared_ptr` instance `p` that *owns* `&t` **and any other `shared_ptr` instances that own `&t` shall share ownership with `p`**.

This isn't quite sufficient though, because your example meets that requirement: at the second call to `shared_from_this()` there is only one owner (`p1`) but you've already "corrupted" the state of the `enable_shared_from_this` base class by calling `lock2()`.

A smaller form of the program is:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  struct X : public enable_shared_from_this<X> { };
  auto xraw = new X;
  shared_ptr<X> xp1(xraw);   // #1
  {
    shared_ptr<X> xp2(xraw, [](void*) { });  // #2
  }
  xraw->shared_from_this();  // #3
}
```

All three of libstdc++, libc++ and VC++ (Dinkumware) behave the same and throw `bad_weak_ptr` at #3, because at #2 they update the `weak_ptr<X>` member of the base class to make it share ownership with `xp2`, which goes out of scope leaving the `weak_ptr<X>` in the expired state.

Interestingly `boost::shared_ptr` doesn't throw, instead #2 is a no-op and #3 returns a `shared_ptr` that shares ownership with `xp1`. This was done in response to a [bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2584) with almost exactly the same example as the one above.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a defect here in C++11. In allowing this:

> It's a bit unusual to have two shared_ptr objects store the same pointer &x but not share ownership, and to use "deleters" that do not end the lifetime of *get(), but nothing forbids it.

This should be explicitly stated to be undefined behavior, *regardless* of what the "deleters" do. Sure, it may be technically not illegal to do things that way.

However, you are *lying* to people who use the code. The expectation of anyone who receives a `shared_ptr` is that they now have ownership of the object. So long as they keep that `shared_ptr` (or a copy thereof) around, the object it points to will still exists.

That is not the case with your code. So I would say that it is syntactically correct but semantically invalid.

The language for `shared_from_this` is fine. It's the language for `shared_ptr` that needs changing. It should state that it is undefined behavior to create two separate unique pointers that "own" the same pointer.

Comment: Is `shared_ptr<Y> p1(nullptr, d1); shared_ptr<Z> p2(nullptr, d2);` just as invalid?

Comment: What if I give `x` static storage duration and make the ctor and dtor of `X` private?  Then I really can guarantee that if you have a non-empty `shared_ptr<X>`, the object it points to still exists (because it always exists).

Comment: Not trying to shoot this down: I think the basic idea would make a good fix to the Standard, but it would need some more careful wording.

Comment: @aschepler: "What if I give x static storage duration and make the ctor and dtor of X private?" So what if you do? It's still lying to the user by sticking it in a `shared_ptr`, because the `shared_ptr` doesn't *own* it. The lifetime is controlled elsewhere. If you're not handling ownership semantics with `shared_ptr`, then you shouldn't be using it at all.

Comment: Well, yes. I definitely "should" never write code like this. Unfortunately, there's little room for "should" in a Standard.

Comment: @aschepler: That's why I said the standard *should* declare it undefined behavior. Whether it *could* work is irrelevant; it's wrong and should be forbidden.

Comment: @aschepler "_give x static storage duration_" still *not* the proper semantic: holding an owning "smart pointer" (`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`...) is like a lock on the lifetime of the object, it should be enough to keep the target, but a static object with a non trivial dtor is still destructed at some point during program execution, unless the dtor body consists only of a call to `_exit()`, then the destruction is never observable (entering the body of the dtor officially ends the lifetime, but in reality is does nothing)

Comment: @NicolBolas "_because the shared_ptr doesn't own it. The lifetime is controlled elsewhere_" "control" is subjective in case of "shared ownership" anyway, unlike exclusive ownership (`unique_ptr` as well as a `shared_ptr` that is `.unique()`); exclusive ownership is real ownership with the attribute of legal ownership: it can be given away. (Although `shared_ptr` doesn't support a `.release()` operation, it could with the precondition `.unique()`.) OTOH, shared ownership is a very vague notion because you don't know who shares it and what there intent it. You don't have control in that case.

Comment: (...) Keeping around a `shared_ptr` that is shared just means that you prevent the execution of its "deleter", not that you can locally (without considering the rest of the program) determine when the "deleter" will run. And you shouldn't care either, it's the point of "shared" ownership. In fact another copy of that `shared_ptr` could reside in static variable so the "deleter" would run only after main returns. That shouldn't be a problem for the consumer of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @aschepler Stopping a program to "preserve" program invariants might not be an acceptable approach in all cases, of course. It's like `assert` or throw-specifications: better stopped than running in a state that breaks design principles.

Answer (score 0):

This issue and other related ones were clarified in C++17.  Now `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` is specified as if having a single `std::weak_ptr<T> weak_this;` member.  For a non-array specialization of `std::shared_ptr`, that member is assigned by `std::shared_ptr` constructors, `std::make_shared`, and `std::allocate_shared` as described in [util.smartptr.shared.const]/1:

> Enables `shared_­from_­this` with `p`, for a pointer `p` of type `Y*`, means that if `Y` has an unambiguous and accessible base class that is a specialization of `enable_­shared_­from_­this`, then `remove_­cv_­t<Y>*` shall be implicitly convertible to `T*` and the constructor evaluates the statement:
>
> ```
> if (p != nullptr && p->weak_this.expired())
>   p->weak_this = shared_ptr<remove_cv_t<Y>>(*this, const_cast<remove_cv_t<Y>*>(p));
> ```

So the correct behavior of the second `main` in my OP is now that no exception will be thrown and both "not empty" checks will show true.  Since at the call to `lock2()` the internal `weak_ptr` is already owned and therefore not `expired()`, `lock2()` leaves the `weak_ptr` unchanged, and so the second call to `shared_from_this()` returns a `shared_ptr` which shared ownership with `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  X x;
  std::shared_ptr<X> p1 = x.lock1();
  (...sniped...)
}
```

Such code is breaks the semantics of "owning" "smart pointers":

- they can be copied
- as long as one copy is kept around, the owned object is kept around

This invariant is so essential, I'd argue that such practice should be rejected by code review. But there is a variant of what you suggest that satisfies the invariant:

- the object must be dynamically managed (so, not automatic)
- any family of owning objects has shared ownership of the dynamically managed object
- each member of a family has shared ownership of the "deleter" of that family

So here we have shared owning objects that are part of different "families" of owning objects, they aren't "equivalent" as they have different:

- "deleters" object
- `use_count()` values
- control blocks
- `owner_before` results

but they all prevent the destruction of the same object; this is done by keeping a copy of the `shared_ptr` in each and every "deleter" object.

A clean replacement for `std::shared_from_this` is used to have complete control over the initialization of the `std::weak_ptr<T>` member.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

// essentially like std::shared_from_this
// unlike std::shared_from_this the initialization IS NOT implicit
// calling set_owner forces YOU to THINK about what you are doing!

template <typename T>
class my_shared_from_this
{
    std::weak_ptr<T> weak;
public:
    void set_owner(std::shared_ptr<T>);
    std::shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this() const;
};

// shall be called exactly once
template <typename T>
void my_shared_from_this<T>::set_owner(std::shared_ptr<T> shared)
{
    assert (weak.expired());
    weak = shared;
}

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> my_shared_from_this<T>::shared_from_this() const
{
    assert (!weak.expired());
    return weak.lock();
}

class X : public my_shared_from_this<X>
{
public:
  struct Cleanup1 { 
    std::shared_ptr<X> own;
    Cleanup1 (std::shared_ptr<X> own) : own(own) {}
    void operator()(X*) const; 
  };

  struct Cleanup2 { 
    std::shared_ptr<X> own;
    Cleanup2 (std::shared_ptr<X> own) : own(own) {}
    void operator()(X*) const; 
  };

  std::shared_ptr<X> lock1();
  std::shared_ptr<X> lock2();

  X();
  ~X();
};

// new shared owner family with shared ownership with the other ones
std::shared_ptr<X> X::lock1()
{
  std::cout << "Resource 1 locked" << std::endl;
  // do NOT call set_owner here!!!
  return std::shared_ptr<X>(this, Cleanup1(shared_from_this()));
}

std::shared_ptr<X> X::lock2()
{
  std::cout << "Resource 2 locked" << std::endl;
  return std::shared_ptr<X>(this, Cleanup2(shared_from_this()));
}

void X::Cleanup1::operator()(X*) const
{
  std::cout << "Resource 1 unlocked" << std::endl;
}

void X::Cleanup2::operator()(X*) const
{
  std::cout << "Resource 2 unlocked" << std::endl;
}

X::X()
{
  std::cout << "X()" << std::endl;
}

X::~X()
{
  std::cout << "~X()" << std::endl;
}

// exposes construction and destruction of global vars
struct GlobDest {
  int id;
  explicit GlobDest(int id);
  ~GlobDest();
};

GlobDest::GlobDest(int id) 
  : id(id) 
{
    std::cout << "construction of glob_dest #" << id << std::endl;
}

GlobDest::~GlobDest() {
    std::cout << "destruction of glob_dest #" << id << std::endl;
}

GlobDest glob_dest0 {0};
std::shared_ptr<X> glob;
GlobDest glob_dest1 {1};

std::shared_ptr<X> make_shared_X()
{
    std::cout << "make_shared_X" << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<X> p = std::make_shared<X>();
    p->set_owner(p);
    return p;
}

int test()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  std::shared_ptr<X> p = make_shared_X();
  static std::shared_ptr<X> stat;
  {
    std::shared_ptr<X> p1 = p->lock1();
    stat = p1;
    {
      std::shared_ptr<X> p2 = p->lock2();
      glob = p2;
      std::cout << "exit scope of p2" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "exit scope of p1" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "exit scope of p" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  test();
  std::cout << "exit main" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
construction of glob_dest #0
construction of glob_dest #1
make_shared_X
X()
Resource 1 locked
Resource 2 locked
exit scope of p2
exit scope of p1
exit scope of p
exit main
Resource 1 unlocked
destruction of glob_dest #1
Resource 2 unlocked
~X()
destruction of glob_dest #0
```